# how to best export / import an array of THREE.Vector3 from a file in three.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, three.js

I have a large array of `THREE.Vector3()` that I'd like to save to a JSON file to read in later.

I can write it as `JSON.stringify(Points)`, which outputs an array of objects as follows:

```
  "Points": [
        {"x":115,"y":0,"z":-250},
        {"x":115,"y":0,"z":-220},
        {"x":115,"y":0,"z":-190},
        ...
  ]
```

Now if I turn around and read this back in, I loose my three.js vecotrs and must individually re-assign them as follows:

```
   newPoint[nn] = new THREE.Vector3(jsonData.Points[nn].x,jsonData.Points[nn].y,jsonData.Points[nn].z);
```

Maybe I'm just hoping for some kind of magic, but I feel like this can be more efficient. Is there a better way to read/write an array of three.js vectors in JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I have similar task in my project. I just use array of floats to keep points. It allows to reduce file size. For instance:

```
{
    points: [x0, y0, z0, x1, y1, z1, ..., xn, yn, zn]
}
```

Also it's possible to group coordinates [image]

To keep THREE.Vector3 objects you can use js files:

```
var pointList = [new THREE.Vector3(x0, y0, z0), new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1, z1), ..., new THREE.Vector3(xn, yn, zn)];
```

Comment: It takes some time to load a json file with points and create a list of THREE.Vector3 objects. It worth to consider usage of workers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I noticed in r72 there is now an `object3D.toJSON()` function, so I'm excited about that and look forward to using it.

Comment: however I'm still wondering if `toJSON()` exists for something like an array of THREE.Vector3() and not just for objects....

Answer (score 0):

Example PART1. You can re_create yours three.Vector3 with a for loop;

```
//Let's assume, at a given time you have this arrays;

let x_array=[-10,-5,20,10];
let y_array=[0,15,15,0];
let z_array=[0,0,0,0];


//This loop re_create yours three.Vector3;
let array_of_threejs_points=[];
let i=0;
for(i=0; i<x_array.length; i++)
{
    array_of_threejs_points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x_array[i],y_array[i],z_array[i]));
}


console.log('array_of_threejs_points'); 
console.log(array_of_threejs_points);
```

Example Part2.
Pass these three.Vector3 to a curve, in this example the BezierCurve.

```
let curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(array_of_threejs_points[0], array_of_threejs_points[1], array_of_threejs_points[2], array_of_threejs_points[3]);
```

Yes. I know. The PART2 should be enhanced;

PS1. In this example a threejs_point is a three.Vector3 object.

PS2. In this example the most important instruction is:

`array_of_threejs_points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x_array[i],y_array[i],z_array[i]));`